# Xcode Archiving always Fail

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]

I always get this error message whenever I archive my project. I have already deleted the Derived Data, Provisioning Profiles. Installed a new Provisioning Profile and rebuilt the project. But whenever I do archiving, it always fail.

Comment: I see a `.sh` file being listed in the build log.  Is there a build script in your Xcode project's build settings?  If so, could you edit and copy/paste it into your question?

Comment: The error seems to be coming from SwiftLint.

Comment: SO I just deleted the Build Script in Build Phase, it seems like it's not being used anyway.

Comment: do you use `swiftlint` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode Project -> Build Phases

Remove the Run script containing

```
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
   swiftlint
else
   echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from
   https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

Clean and Archive